# C11 and C++11 atomics: acquire-release semantics and memory barriers

Tags: c++11, assembly, atomic, c11, memory-fences

I'm using C11* atomics to manage a state enum between a few threads. The code resembles the following:

```
static _Atomic State state;

void setToFoo(void)
{
    atomic_store_explicit(&state, STATE_FOO, memory_order_release);
}

bool stateIsBar(void)
{
    return atomic_load_explicit(&state, memory_order_acquire) == STATE_BAR;
}
```

This assembles (for an ARM Cortex-M4) to:

```
<setToFoo>:
   ldr  r3, [pc, #8]
   dmb  sy ; Memory barrier
   movs r2, #0
   strb r2, [r3, #0] ; store STATE_FOO
   bx   lr
   .word    0x00000000

<stateIsBar>:
  ldr   r3, [pc, #16]
  ldrb  r0, [r3, #0] ; load state
  dmb   sy ; Memory barrier
  sub.w r0, r0, #2 ; Comparison and return follows
  clz   r0, r0
  lsrs  r0, r0, #5
  bx    lr
  .word 0x00000000
```

Why are the fences placed *before* the release and *after* the acquire? My mental model assumed that a barrier would be placed after *after* a release (to "propagate" the variable being stored and all other stores to other threads) and *before* an acquire (to receive all previous stores from other threads).

---

*While this particular example is given in C11, the situation is identical in C++11, as the two share the same concepts (and even the same enums) when it comes to memory ordering. `gcc` and `g++` emit the same machine code in this situation. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/memory_order and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order

Comment: In `stateIsBar(void)`, did you mean to `return` that expression?  Because as written, it's a function with no return statement that doesn't return void.  It should compile to a single return instruction (actually, the memory barrier is still needed, but not the load).

Comment: Correct - thanks for catching the typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The memory fence before the store is to guarantee that the store isn't ordered before any prior stores.  Similarly, the memory fence after the read guarantees that the read isn't ordered after any following reads.  When you combine the two, it creates a *synchronizes-with* relation between the writes and reads.

```
T1: on-deps(A) -> fence -> write(A)

T2: read(A) -> fence -> deps-on(A)
```

read(A) happens before deps-on(A)

write(A) happens after on-deps(A)

If you change the order of either fence, the sequence of dependencies is broken which obviously will cause inconsistent results (e.g. race conditions).

Some more possible reading...

- [Acquire and Release Fences](http://preshing.com/20130922/acquire-and-release-fences/)
- [Memory Barriers: a Hardware View for Software Hackers](http://www.rdrop.com/users/paulmck/scalability/paper/whymb.2009.04.05a.pdf)